# Not able to upload a file with chrome and ftpwebrequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing functionality in my MVC 5 application (using the ftpWebRequest class) to let the user select a file via a form and then upload it to an ftp server. In IE it al works fine but when I switch to chrome/firefox/safari I get stuck, because these browsers use something like **c:\fakepath\examplefile.png**
Is there a way to also upload files using chrome/firefox/safari?

**html**

```
<form id="frmUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileN" id="file" />
</form>
<button id="btnUploadx">Upload</button>
```

**Script**

```
$("#btnUploadx").on("click", function () {
    uploadFile();            
});

function uploadFile() {

    var formData = new FormData($('#frmUpload')[0]);

    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "@urlPath/Ftp/AjaxUploadFile/");
    ajax.send(formData);
 }
```

**Action AjaxUploadFile**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AjaxUploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileN, string folder)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> strMsg = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    completePath = System.IO.Path.
                       GetFullPath(Request.Files["fileN"].FileName);
    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(completePath);

    string strFtp = "ftp://" + serverIp + "/folder/" + fileName;

        try
        {

            FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strFtp);
            ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
            ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

            ftpReq.ContentLength = fileN.ContentLength;

            byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(completePath);
            ftpReq.ContentLength = b.Length;

            using (Stream s = ftpReq.GetRequestStream())
            {
                s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            }

            FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", "OrderLine", new { id = folder });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Details", "OrderLine", new { id = folder });
        }


    }
```

Comment: You need to show your code. Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't show us what you're doing.

Comment: Of course they use `c:\fakepath\examplefile.png`. That what's your supposed to see (for security reasons)

Comment: @mason I've edited the question and I think I've also found the solution.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. Post your solution as an answer, explaining what you did to fix it. Don't post your solution as part of the question. You should still provide your original code in the question so that others may learn from it.

Comment: @mason hope it's clear now.

Comment: As you are getting the fileN as an input, instead of  
`System.IO.Path.                      GetFullPath(Request.Files["fileN"].FileName);` 

you could use this instead:
 
`using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileN.Attachment.InputStream))
            {
                byte[] b = reader.ReadBytes(fileN.Attachment.ContentLength);
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more tests, I found the solution in changing the byte[] part in the controller/action. I had to change:

```
byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(completePath);
ftpReq.ContentLength = b.Length;
```

into

```
byte[] b = null;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["fileN"].InputStream))
{
    b = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files["fileN"].ContentLength);
}
```

Comment: The reason for that is that the browser doesn't provide the full path of uploaded files to the server, for security reasons. It just provides the filename.